# Adjust FAQ for cost of a job

Tags: feature-request

Please adjust the FAQ:

```
Note, the following are considered off-topic:

The cost of a job or the price of tools as these will vary between locations and over time.
```

to include a clear comment regarding questions about tipping contractors being off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the challenge with a list like this is that it will never explicitly describe every single off topic question, and trying to do so would result in a l,000 item list that no one would ever read. Instead, we've tried to keep it high level and broad, when possible removing or consolidating items. So I'm inclined to decline this request, but I'm happy to follow the community if they disagree with me.

Comment: I understand that concern, but in my area tipping contractors is common, and in some areas it isn't. I recently asked about it on the main forum and was told it's off-topic, but the text really doesn't preclude it because it's not the cost of a job.  I was looking for a percentage to go by maybe based on the cost of the job,

Comment: I agree with the others that tipping is too localized. For a description of why some questions would be closed, see [this section](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#close) of the [faq].

Comment: Maybe a reasonable compromise would be, "The cost of a job (including speculating labor, materials, and permit prices) or the price of tools...." ?

Comment: Maybe "Cost, pricing, and payment as these will vary between locations and over time." Take out whether it's for a project or for tools, since any purpose is too localized. This is just my opinion, so if the community disagrees, I'm happy to follow their lead.